# Why is the scan line filling algorithm for computer graphics so complicated?

Tags: graphics

It seems to me that the algorithm is over complicated.

It makes use of tables, buckets, and sorting, which all seem unnecessary.

I don't understand why I can't just fill between pairs of scan line intersections, ignoring vertices and edges with gradient 0.

My lecturer didn't provide the best notes on this algorithm, and all I can find online are even more complicated versions of it.

An ideal answer would be an explanation of the algorithm, and a reason why simply filling between pairs of intersections won't work.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean Smith's fill? Or AET rasterizer? I am afraid that your question is too much about your lecturer and problems, but too little about actual algorithm that seems problematic. Could you update your question to include unambiguous name of the algorithm, pseudocode (and include your concerns as the comments)? Also the question should be self-contained, so external link with code wouldn't be ok. The fast answer is: this algorithm exists for some time now (doesn't matter if it is one of those I've guessed or another one). It is efficient and handles corner cases.

Comment: It may happen that you came up with something better, but first try to understand the original one, check if yours handles all corner cases and then compare them.